# Ubuntu: Kernel#system fails (returns nil) when running the Unix "hash" command

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu, rubygems

I ran into an interesting problem while developing a gem that only seems to happen on Ubuntu. My Ruby is version 2.2.2 installed with the rbenv tool. I am building a CLI (Tool A) that depends on another utility (Tool B) being installed on the machine. At the point when Tool B is called there is a guard clause that prints an error message if Tool B isn't found, like this:

`fail "Can't do it: missing 'Tool B' utility" unless system("hash tool-b")`

I had no problems with this on OSX, but on Ubuntu `system("hash tool-b")` always returns `nil` (command failed). When printing the exit code from within a Ruby interpreter (`$?`), I get `127` instead of `0`.

The strange thing is that if I run `hash tool-b` directly from the command line, the process exits successfully with a status of `0`. This seems to happen for me when checking for *any* utility on Ubuntu from within Ruby with `system("hash <utility>")`. I've changed the program to use `system("which tool-b")` instead of `hash` but am still interested to know if there is something particular to my setup that might be doing this (it's a vanilla Ubuntu 14.04 box on Amazon EC2 with pretty much nothing but rbenv, Ruby 2.2.2, and my gems), or something about Ubuntu + Ruby that I don't get.

Summary of the commands I'm running on the different platforms:

```
fail "Can't create cartridge: missing 'cartridge' utility" unless system("hash cartridge") # offending Ruby code

### UBUNTU COMMAND LINE
$ hash cartridge
$ echo $?
=> 0

### UBUNTU IRB
system("hash cartridge")
=> nil
puts $?
=> ... exit 127

### OSX IRB
system("hash cartridge")
=> true
puts $?
=> ... exit 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Kernel#system` uses the system shell, i.e. `/bin/sh` to execute. `hash` was only added to the Base System in POSIX.2013, before that, it was optional. I believe `dash`, the default system shell Ubuntu uses is not yet POSIX.2013 compliant, and thus does not have `hash` (yet).

macOS / OSX uses Bash as its system shell, which *does* have `hash`.